# Recursive function return tuples of even index values?

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

Is it possible to return tuples of only even indexes through recursion?

This is what I came up with it so far.

```
def even(tup):
    if not tup:
        return ()
    if tup.index(tup[0])+1 % 2 == 0:
        return tuple(tup[0]) + even(tup[1:])
```

Passed argument gonna be look like this:

```
('c','b','z','e','m','f','j')
```

And my desired result would be:

First element in the tuple count as 1 = 'c', so for the even numbers it would return b, e, and f instead.

```
('b','e','f')
```

There are some requirements that I cannot mutate or re assigning the parameter at all.

What's the best way to approach this recursion?
I can solve this if it was list of numbers, but having a problem with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to come up with this recursive strategy. A noob strategy, I guess. :P

```
a = ('c','b','z','e','m','f','j')

def recFunc(a, theIndex):
    if theIndex%2 == 1:
        if theIndex < len(a):
            value = recFunc(a, theIndex+1)
            return (a[theIndex], ) + value
        else:
            return ()
    else:
        return (recFunc(a, theIndex+1))

print(recFunc(a, 0))
```

It seems to be self-explanatory. :)

**Note:** Maximum depth reaches at ~1000 elements.

**EDIT:** If you cannot add any other parameter and change it, how about such a solution (inspired from your work)?

```
def recFunc(a):
    if len(a) == 0 or len(a) == 1:
        return ()
    # print(a)
    return (a[1],) + recFunc(a[2:])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot modify the parameter! That's why I was trying to use the index slicing with my code.

Comment: G̶l̶o̶b̶a̶l̶ ̶V̶a̶r̶i̶a̶b̶l̶e̶s̶ ̶. It's a noob solution. Let me see, if I can come up with something.

Comment: But the tuples are immutable, so I don't think modifying works

Comment: The tuples are immutable, I agree. But what if you just don't edit the existing tuple, but replace it? See the edited solution.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want just something like this?

```
tup = tuple(item for i, item in enumerate(tup) if i % 2 == 1)
```

Recursive function is unnecessary here. If you want to operate with `tuple()` items I would recommend you to cast it to `list()`.

Also I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here:

```
if tup.index(tup[0])+1 % 2 == 0:
```

- `tup[0]` returns first element
- `tup.index(tup[0])` returns index of first element => `0`
- then `0+1 % 2 == 0` is always `False`

---

#### Edit:

But recursive function that returns tuple of "even" index values could look like this:

```
def even(tup):
  if len(tup) <= 1:
    return
  elif len(tup) <= 3:
    return tup[1]
  return (tup[1], *even(tup[2:]))
```